# Mean subtraction of patches in python nympy scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array of 3 dimension, it's a grid of patches of 8x8 images.

What is the best way to subtract from each patch it's average, in other words each patch has a unique mean and I want to subtract it. I tried the following with no success obviously because both arrays are not equal in shape

```
patches=- patches.mean(axis = 2).mean(axis = 1)
```

I thought of using the repeat function, something like:

```
patches=- np.repeat(np.repeat(patches.mean(axis =2).mean(axis =1).reshape((n_patches, 8, 8)), 1, 1))
```

Put I think that following this route would lead to an inefficient solution. Any thoughts or solution on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for broadcasting:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: Almost that, I ended up using patches.mean(axis = 2).mean(axis = 1).reshape(n_patches, 1, 1) I readjusted the shape to allow broadcasting...

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10,8,8)
mean = a.mean(axis=2).mean(axis=1)
b = a - mean[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] # reshape the mean as (10, 1, 1)
```